# Windows 7 Bootloader on restart and Windows 8 bootloader on Shutdown

Tags: bootloader

Recently i had 3 OS on my system . First i installed Windows 7 . Then windows 8 rtm. then fedora. Everything went great. I always saw windows 8 bootloader. ( ofcourse it didnt show fedora in it ). So i used easyBCD to add fedora .. And i made it to work. So now i have Windows 8 bootloader and it shows win7 , win 8 , and fedora. Everything was fine.

Now the Real problem : I removed fedora from partition ( deleted its volume) and then removed its entry from easyBCD.
Now what happens is if I am in windows 8 and i shutdown and start again i get win8 bootloader but if i am in win8 and i RESTART then i get win7 bootloader instead.
Any idea why it happens. ? (hope u guys understood the ques)

Comment: You'll have you repair the BCD for Windows 7, then do the same from 8.